# SqlAlchemy changes in Model description not applied in DB

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently developing a server using Flask/SqlAlchemy. It occurs that when an ORM model is not present as a table in the database, it is created by default by SqlAlchemy.

However when an ORM class is changed with for instance an extra column is added, these changes do not get saved in the database. So the extra column will be missing, every time I query. I have to adjust my DB manually every time there is a change in the models that I use.

Is there a better way to apply changes in the models during development? I hardly think manual MySql manipulation is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can proceed as the following:

```
new_column = Column('new_column', String, default='some_default_value')
new_column.create(my_table, populate_default=True)
```

you can find more details about sqlalchemy migration in: https://sqlalchemy-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changeset.html