# How to do database schema migrations in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask and sqlalchemy to create backend. When I change my schema(example- I add a column or delete a column ) then there is no change in the database tables.
How to do this database migrations?
In Django it is pretty simple
 `python manage.py migrate`

Is something like this possible in sqlalchemy?

Comment: Take a look here: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

Comment: sure i will take a look into it.
I found a similar question on stackoverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832827/sqlalchemy-changes-in-model-description-not-applied-in-db

Will this work ?

Comment: https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: with the SO question/answer mentioned above you have double work: you need to adapt your model and you have to write your migrations manually. Better check out the link I provided: there you adapt the model, and flask-migrate does the rest for you.